# How to import excel stored data in MySQL and keep date format as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, csv, import

I have come across somewhat difficult task to complete. I have an excel document with various columns and two of them are date columns with values in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

I need to import all this data in MySQL and so far tried to do it with a CSV file using phpmyadmin.

The problem is that CSV is changing the date format from `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

What other ways exist to import data originating from excel file into MySQL and keep the data format?

I would appreciate some simple solution if such exists.

Thank you!

Comment: please post your SQL create table and (csv) import statements you tried.

Comment: Why not import straight from Excel with the SQL Import wizard?

Comment: Try http://excel2mysql.net .. it will store your date & times in proper mysql datetime, date, or time fields automatically if you check the optimize field option.  This is the simplest option and it is free to try, but not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with importing Excel files into MySQL, in SQL Server this is trivial using the import wizard so I'd assume something similar exists for MySQL.

If you need to, you can convert the value to text with the format of your choosing in Excel with the following:

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
```

This format will persist in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question here - one possibility to export dates from excel into CSV file and keep the date format as `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is to save the file as .ods document - the file format of Open Office.

From the .ods file you can save your document as CSV file and the dates are being kept as `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. For some reason Open Office keeps the selected date format when saving into CSV and Excel does not.

Hope this helps someone.